# How to hide CSS2DObject?

Tags: three.js

I created the CSS2DObject object using the following code：

```
self.labelDiv = document.createElement( 'div' );
self.labelDiv.className = 'label';      
self.labelDiv.innerHTML = textshow;
var label = new THREE.CSS2DObject( self.labelDiv );
label.position.set(obj.x, obj.y, obj.z);
```

And added CSS2DRenderer：

```
this.labelRenderer = new THREE.CSS2DRenderer();
```

Now I want to dynamically control the display and hiding of the label,but I have no effect after setting the visible property.

```
label.visible = false;
```

How should I control the label? Thanks.

Comment: I solved the problem. I dynamically removed the CSS2DObject and saved it to the list, then adding it when needed.

Comment: Another way it to do this: `label.element.style.display = 'none';`.

Comment: @ Mugen87 Your method is effective, thank you.